# How to animate an image on a click using angular-animations

Tags: angular, angular-animations

This animation works when the page loads,But I need to animate this image on a button click

```
<div [@fadeInDownOnEnter]="'true'">
    <img src="https://www.seoclerk.com/pics/556744-1wYpi51504622425.jpg" alt="animatepic">
</div>
<button (click)="animate()">Animate it</button>
```

in component.ts file

```
import { fadeInDownOnEnterAnimation } from 'angular-animations';
@Component({
  animations: [
    fadeInDownOnEnterAnimation()
  ]
})


//method 
animate(){
  //what should I do here
}
```

Comment: Please show us the code in your animations fadeInDownOnEnterAnimation() else someone will vote down this question soon

Answer (score 7, accepted):

in your component ,

```
    animationWithState = false;
    animate(){
    this.animationState=true;
    this.animationWithState = !this.animationWithState;
    }, 1);
```

and

```
<div [@fadeInDownOnEnter]="'true'">
```

this should be like

```
<div [@fadeInDownOnEnter]="animationState">
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a static value `'true'` in your template, set the value of the `[@fadeInDownOnEnter]` attribute to a variable that will be referenced from your component like so

```
<div [@fadeInDownOnEnter]="animationState" >
  <img src="https://www.seoclerk.com/pics/556744-1wYpi51504622425.jpg" alt="animatepic">
</div>
<button (click)="animate()" >Animate it</button>
```

Then in your component

```
import {fadeInDownOnEnterAnimation} from 'angular-animations';
@Component({
  animations:[
        fadeInDownOnEnterAnimation()
     ]
})

animationState  = 'true';
//method 
animate(){
    //what should I do here
    this.animationState = this.animationState === 'true' ? 'false' : 'true';
    // the code above will toggle the value of animationState between 'true' and 'false'
    // in order to update the animation

}
```

Comment: I think 'true' should be just true